# $Sin(nx)$ always 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

It may seem naive, but, is there any value for $x$ in $$\sin(nx)$$ such that for any natural $n$, $\sin(nx)$ = $1$? 
I've tried quite a few values, and I seem to fail at avoiding it going to zero.
Or even to make it alternate between $-1$ and $1$
Surely it must be possible to do so?

Comment: Look at the graph.

Comment: What make you so "sure" it must be possible to do so? Surely you must have noted how for every such attempt either $\sin(x)\ne\pm1$ or $\sin(2x)=0$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin nx=1\iff nx=\frac\pi2+2k\pi.$$

This is impossible, as $n=1$ says

$$x=\frac\pi2+2k\pi,$$ and with $n=2$,

$$x=\frac\pi4+k'\pi.$$

Together,

$$\frac12+2k=\frac14+k'\ !$$

Comment: Why $k'$ factorial? :)

Comment: @S.C.B.: haha...

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible for $\sin nx=0$ for all $n$.

If $\sin x=1$, from $\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x=0$,  we know that $\cos x=0$ if $\sin x=1$. But since $$\sin 2x=2 \sin x \cos x=2 \times 1 \times 0$$

Hence, $\sin 2x=0$ if $\sin x=1$, and since if fails at the natural $2$, what you're trying is impossible.

Comment: Note that this argument works even if we allow $x$ to have complex value. Even in the complex case we have $\cos^2 z = 1-\sin^2 z$ and $\sin 2z = 2\sin z\cos z$ so if $\sin z=\pm 1$ we must have $\sin 2z=0$.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any value for $x$ in $$\sin(nx)$$ such that for any natural $n$, $\sin(nx)$ = $1$?

I'm assuming $\mathbb{N}$ to include $0$, then no: because for any $x$, you will always have
$$\sin(0x) = \sin 0 = 0 \quad \mbox{for} \quad n=0$$

You can achieve what you're looking for (a 'suitable' $x$) if you allow something of the form:
$$\sin\left( \tfrac{\pi}{2} + nx\right)$$

---

Addition after comment, since you seem to exclude $0$.

If you want $\sin(nx)=1$ for all $n$, taking $n=1$ implies that $x$ has to be of the form $\tfrac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. But taking $n=2$ implies $x$ has to be of the form $\tfrac{\pi}{4}+k\pi$ and no $x$ can be of both forms.

Comment: It says **natural** $n$. I don't think $0$ is a natural.

Comment: $n$ being in the naturals. I'm avoiding $n=0$

Comment: $0$ is a natural and not a natural

Comment: @S.C.B. I assumed 'naturals' to include $0$ but your comment reminded me that this is not universal; I'll add this caveat.